# PHP отправка писем на @mail

Tags: php, sendmail

Столкнулся с проблемой отправки писем. Почитал разные статейки, в основном у людей проблема самой отправки и что-то в этом деле. Но у меня же письмо отправляется на @gmail | @yandex , а на @mail не хочет. То есть письма нету нигде. Что может быть не так с этим делом? Пробовал писать разные почты, от несуществующих до своих же. На первые две всё нормально  доходит, но никак не на мыльцо.

---

### Вот пример php :

```
$Message = $_POST['message'];
$To      = $_POST['to'];
$From    = $_POST['from'];
$Subject = $_POST['subject'];

$Headers = "From: $From\r\nReply-to: $From\r\nContent-type:text/html; charset=utf8\r\n";

if(!empty($To) && !empty($From))
{
    $result = SendMail($Message, $To, $Subject, $Headers);
}
```

---

Comment: Про ужесточение политики DMARC у мэйл.ру читали?

Comment: Конечно же нет, впервые слышу о таком. Сейчас прочитаю. Но на моём хостинге, когда я написал им о своей проблеме, сказали проверить header , From отправляет не то. И да, письмо на почту пришло, но в папку спам и когда я открыл, там было письмо от mail'a где они написали, мол проблема `A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно говоря, решил проблему. Помогла и поддержка моего хостинга.
У тех, у кого не отправляется только на @mail.ru проверьте $header
И php.ini . 
В моём случае вот такие данные помогли решить проблему:

**php**

```
 $headers    = "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
 $headers    .= "From: noreplay@weap-shop.ru\r\n";
```

---

**php.ini**

```
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f noreply@weap-shop.ru"
```

---

После этого, письма нормально доходили на любую почту. Пробуйте.